# WebPack Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` error in an Angular5 application  - none CLI. I understand the Webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) should create some globals, but i have it configured. I am not sure why the process is not available - I have confirmed this in the REPL.

I'm new to Webpack and don't know where to start looking. Can anyone help?

Webpack config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');
const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');

module.exports = function (options) {
  const isProd = options.env === 'production';
  const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, options.metadata || {});
  const ngcWebpackConfig = buildUtils.ngcWebpackSetup(isProd, METADATA);
  const supportES2015 = buildUtils.supportES2015(METADATA.tsConfigPath);

  const entry = {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    vendor:    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
    main:      './src/main.browser.ts'
  };

  Object.assign(ngcWebpackConfig.plugin, {
    tsConfigPath: METADATA.tsConfigPath,
    mainPath: entry.main
  });

  return {
    performance: { hints: false },
    entry: entry,
    resolve: {
      mainFields: [ ...(supportES2015 ? ['es2015'] : []), 'browser', 'module', 'main' ],
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],
      alias: buildUtils.rxjsAlias(supportES2015)
    },

    module: {

      rules: [
        ...ngcWebpackConfig.loaders,
        { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
        { test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/, use: 'url?limit=10000&name=[name].[ext]' },
        { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, use: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        }

      ],

    },
    plugins: [
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'AOT': METADATA.AOT,
        'process.env.ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'process.env.HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(METADATA.API_URL)
      }),

      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
      }),

      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        minChunks: Infinity,
        name: 'inline'
      }),
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'main',
        async: 'common',
        children: true,
        minChunks: 2
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: 'src/assets',
        to: 'assets'
      }]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
          const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];
          return entryPoints.indexOf(a.names[0]) - entryPoints.indexOf(b.names[0]);
        },
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'body',
        xhtml: true,
        minify: isProd ? {
          caseSensitive: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          keepClosingSlash: true
        } : false
      }),

      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        sync: /inline|polyfills|vendor/,
        defaultAttribute: 'async',
        preload: [/polyfills|vendor|main/],
        prefetch: [/chunk/]
      }),

      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js',
        Hammer: 'hammerjs/hammer',
        Rickshaw: 'rickshaw',
        moment: 'moment',
        fullCalendar: 'fullcalendar',
        Raphael: 'webpack-raphael',
        'window.Raphael': 'webpack-raphael',
        Skycons: 'skycons/skycons',
        Dropzone: 'dropzone',
        tinymce: 'tinymce/tinymce.js'
      }),

      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),
      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin(ngcWebpackConfig.plugin), 
      new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen `process.env.xxx` in a DefinePlugin entry, you could try removing that part:

```
    'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
    'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
    'API_URL': JSON.stringify(METADATA.API_URL)
```

Are these variables you need defined globally for your app or just for your build?

If it's just for your build, You don't need DefinePlugin, just define the variables in the environment like this:

```
    process.env.ENV = JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV);
    process.env.NODE_ENV = JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV);
    process.env.HMR: METADATA.HMR;
    process.env.API_URL: JSON.stringify(METADATA.API_URL);
```

UPDATE

If you want to make those value available to your app, one thing we've done is use the [StringReplaceWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jamesandersen/string-replace-webpack-plugin) to replace string holders with actual values intended for the target environment

```
   {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
            replacements: {
              pattern: /_API_URL_/ig,
              replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                return getApiUrlForEnv(process.env.NODE_ENV);  // implement this
              }
            };
          })
        },
        '@ngtools/webpack'
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the former - I need a way of writing global variables for use in the application. So i can access a global API url, that can be toggled for production and development builds.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my webpack config by adding one simple process flat to true like:

```
 node: {
  global: true,
  crypto: 'empty',
  process: true,
  module: false,
  clearImmediate: false,
  setImmediate: false,
  fs: 'empty'
}
```